# Webpy: how to auto reload source code when it changed?

Tags: python, reload, web.py

I'm learning webpy to write code. 
I'm using Webpy framework 0.34. my operating system is ubuntu 11.04 and python's version is 2.7.
in webpy.org 's [tutorials](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial) it saids:

> "When running with the built-in webserver, it starts the application
>   in debug mode. In debug mode any changes to code and templates are
>   **automatically reloaded**"

but it doesn't work.

my code.py is the same as the tutorial's sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import web
class index():
    def GET(self):
        return 'a'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ('/', 'index')
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

and I am using the build-in webserver(used

```
python code.py
```

to start the server)

when I change the code "return 'a'" to "return 'b'", in web browser, it keeps displaying 'a', untill I restart the server.

restart server every time you rewrite the code is wasting time, why autoreload mechanism does not work? Am I doing something wrong? thank you for any help.

---

**edit**: sorry, my code.py is not exactly the same as the tutorial's sample, that cause the problem. if I put the urls assignment line outside the if statement, the reload mechanism works!!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import web

class index():
    def GET(self):
        return 'a'

urls = ('/', 'index')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

but I don't know why...

Answer (score 2):

if you have separate `route.py` file like me, don't design the file like this:

```
from controllers.index import Index
urls = ('/','Index')
```

it won't reload on document change, do this instead :

```
urls = ('/','controllers.index.Index')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have only one idea: your editor doesn't changing time of modification of your files. Try to enforce changing timestamp by running the following command after code modification and after that check the results:

```
$ touch code.py
```

Comment: thank you for your help, next time I will notice there is another reason :the timestamp changing. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to the top of your code (after imports):

```
web.config.debug = True
```

For more info: http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#developing

Answer (score -1):

you should refresh the page after you change and save the code